# ios crash before launch - black screen on simulator

Tags: ios

```
2014-11-18 16:33:01.840 Record-Upload[2077:112380] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ViewController 0x7f84b3076400> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key PauseButtonTapped.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001049cbf35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001042bbbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001049cbb79 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000103a4a7b3 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 259
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104915e80 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010507dc7d -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1506
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000104edcf98 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 242
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000104edd588 -[UIViewController loadView] + 109
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000104edd7f9 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 75
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000104eddc8e -[UIViewController view] + 27
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000104dfcca9 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 58
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000104dfd041 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 247
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000104e0972c -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000104db4061 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2628
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000104db6d2c -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1350
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000104db5bf2 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    16  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010a9dc2a3 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 16
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010490153c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001048f7285 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001048f7045 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001048f6486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000104db5669 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000104db8420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    23  Record-Upload                       0x0000000103622883 main + 115
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010817b145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I don't understand where it says `reason: '[<ViewController 0x7f9f5304ba00> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key PauseButtonTapped`

There is no line in the code that attempts that
(I hate to just dump the code on here but i feel it is needed)

**code** the program records audio, then puts out using FTP to server

```
#import "NetworkManager.h"
#include <CFNetwork/CFNetwork.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

enum {
    kSendBufferSize = 32768
};

@interface ViewController () <NSStreamDelegate>{
    AVAudioRecorder *recorder;
    AVAudioPlayer *player;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *timer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *startDate;


- (IBAction)sendButtonPush:(id)sender;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *status;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *time;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *sendButton;

@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly ) BOOL              isSending;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSOutputStream *  networkStream;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSInputStream *   fileStream;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly ) uint8_t *         buffer;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) size_t            bufferOffset;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) size_t            bufferLimit;
@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    uint8_t                     _buffer[kSendBufferSize];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.sendButton setEnabled:YES];
    [self.PauseButton setEnabled:NO];
    [self.PlayButton setEnabled: NO];

    //define file path, then file pointer/url
    // NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject], @"MyAudio.m4a", nil];
    // NSURL *outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];

    NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentPath_ = [searchPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pathToSave = [documentPath_ stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"MyAudio2.m4a"];
    NSURL *outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: pathToSave];

    //setup Audio session
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

    //define record settings
    NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    //codec/format
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    //bit rate
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey]; //8000
    //number of channels - stero -2 mono -1?
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

    //initiate and prepare the recorder
    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:NULL];

    recorder.delegate = self;
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}




- (IBAction)sendButtonPush:(id)sender {
    self.status.text = @"...";
    [self.sendButton setEnabled:NO];

    NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentPath_ = [searchPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pathToSave = [documentPath_ stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"MyAudio2.m4a"];
    //NSURL *outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: pathToSave];
    NSLog(@"Path: %@", pathToSave);
    [self startSend: pathToSave];
}


/*
 * Imported From SimpleFTPSample - dev.apple.com
 */
- (void)sendDidStart
{
    self.status.text = @"Sending";
    //self.cancelButton.enabled = YES;
    //[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [[NetworkManager sharedInstance] didStartNetworkOperation];
}

- (void)updateStatus:(NSString *)statusString
{
    assert(statusString != nil);
    self.status.text = statusString;
}

- (void)sendDidStopWithStatus:(NSString *)statusString
{
    if (statusString == nil) {
        statusString = @"Put succeeded";
    }
    self.status.text = statusString;
    //self.cancelButton.enabled = NO;
    //[self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [[NetworkManager sharedInstance] didStopNetworkOperation];
}

#pragma mark * Core transfer code

// This is the code that actually does the networking.

// Because buffer is declared as an array, you have to use a custom getter.
// A synthesised getter doesn't compile.

- (uint8_t *)buffer
{
    return self->_buffer;
}

- (BOOL)isSending
{
    return (self.networkStream != nil);
}

- (void)startSend:(NSString *)filePath
{
    BOOL                    success;
    NSURL *                 url;

    //check path is not empty
    assert(filePath != nil);
    //check path exists
    assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]);
    //check file is either png or jpg
    NSLog(@"FilePath: %@", filePath);
    //assert( [filePath.pathExtension isEqual:@"png"] || [filePath.pathExtension isEqual:@"jpg"] );

    assert(self.networkStream == nil);      // don't tap send twice in a row!
    assert(self.fileStream == nil);         // ditto

    // First get and check the URL - insert our custom url here!
    url = [[NetworkManager sharedInstance] smartURLForString:@"ftp://www.example.co.uk"];
    //check
    success = (url != nil);

    if (success) {
        // Add the last part of the file name to the end of the URL to form the final
        // URL that we're going to put to.

        url = CFBridgingRelease(
                                CFURLCreateCopyAppendingPathComponent(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) url, (__bridge CFStringRef) [filePath lastPathComponent], false)
                                );
        success = (url != nil);
    }

    // If the URL is bogus, let the user know.  Otherwise kick off the connection.
    NSLog(@"URL %@", url);
    if ( ! success) {
        self.status.text = @"Invalid URL";
    } else {

        // Open a stream for the file we're going to send.  We do not open this stream;
        // NSURLConnection will do it for us.

        self.fileStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:filePath];
        assert(self.fileStream != nil);
        //open file stream for input
        [self.fileStream open];

        // Open a CFFTPStream for the URL.

        self.networkStream = CFBridgingRelease(
                                               CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) url)
                                               );
        assert(self.networkStream != nil);
        //
        //User & Password
        //
            success = [self.networkStream setProperty:@"USERNAME" forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPUserName];
            assert(success);
            success = [self.networkStream setProperty:@"PASSWORD" forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPPassword];
            assert(success);


        self.networkStream.delegate = self;
        [self.networkStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [self.networkStream open];

        // Tell the UI we're sending.

        [self sendDidStart];
    }
}

- (void)stopSendWithStatus:(NSString *)statusString
{
    if (self.networkStream != nil) {
        [self.networkStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        self.networkStream.delegate = nil;
        [self.networkStream close];
        self.networkStream = nil;
    }
    if (self.fileStream != nil) {
        [self.fileStream close];
        self.fileStream = nil;
    }
    [self sendDidStopWithStatus:statusString];
}

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode
// An NSStream delegate callback that's called when events happen on our
// network stream.
{
#pragma unused(aStream)
    assert(aStream == self.networkStream);

    switch (eventCode) {
        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted: {
            [self updateStatus:@"Opened connection"];
        } break;
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable: {
            assert(NO);     // should never happen for the output stream
        } break;
        case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable: {
            [self updateStatus:@"Sending"];

            // If we don't have any data buffered, go read the next chunk of data.

            if (self.bufferOffset == self.bufferLimit) {
                NSInteger   bytesRead;

                bytesRead = [self.fileStream read:self.buffer maxLength:kSendBufferSize];

                if (bytesRead == -1) {
                    [self stopSendWithStatus:@"File read error"];
                } else if (bytesRead == 0) {
                    [self stopSendWithStatus:nil];
                } else {
                    self.bufferOffset = 0;
                    self.bufferLimit  = bytesRead;
                }
            }

            // If we're not out of data completely, send the next chunk.

            if (self.bufferOffset != self.bufferLimit) {
                NSInteger   bytesWritten;
                bytesWritten = [self.networkStream write:&self.buffer[self.bufferOffset] maxLength:self.bufferLimit - self.bufferOffset];
                assert(bytesWritten != 0);
                if (bytesWritten == -1) {
                    [self stopSendWithStatus:@"Network write error"];
                } else {
                    self.bufferOffset += bytesWritten;
                }
            }
        } break;
        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred: {
            [self stopSendWithStatus:@"Stream open error"];
        } break;
        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered: {
            // ignore
        } break;
        default: {
            assert(NO);
        } break;
    }
}



- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [self stopSendWithStatus:@"Stopped"];
}
- (IBAction)RecordButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    if(player.playing){
        [player stop];
    }

    if(!recorder.recording){
        AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [session setActive: YES error: nil];
        //start recording
        self.startDate = [NSDate date];
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/100.0
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(updateTimer)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];
        [recorder record];


        [self.RecordButton setTitle: @"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    } else{
        [recorder pause];
        [self.RecordButton setTitle:@"Record" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.timer = nil;
        [self updateTimer];
    }
    [self.PauseButton setEnabled:YES];
    [self.PlayButton setEnabled:NO];
}

//UI Functions
- (IBAction)PauseButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    [recorder stop];
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setActive:NO error: nil];

/*   NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentPath_ = [searchPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSMutableArray *arrayList =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentPath_ error:nil]];
    NSLog(@"==== %@", arrayList); */
}

- (IBAction)PlayButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    if(!recorder.recording){
        player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recorder.url error:nil];
        [player setDelegate:self];
        [player play];
    }
}

//Audio Functions
-(void) audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder successfully:(BOOL)flag{
    [self.RecordButton setTitle: @"Record" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.PauseButton setEnabled:NO];
    [self.PlayButton setEnabled:YES];
}

-(void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" message:@"Finished Playing the recording!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}

//Timer Function
-(void) updateTimer
{


    // Create date from the elapsed time
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:self.startDate];
    NSDate *timerDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];

    // Create a date formatter
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm:ss.SS"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];

    // Format the elapsed time and set it to the label
    NSString *timeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:timerDate];
    self.time.text = timeString;
}

@end
```

Comment: You have missed an outlet connection for `PauseButtonTapped`, connect it with Storyboard/xib.

Comment: i had the the outlet defined in the header, but am rebuilding with them moved to the .m

Comment: Doesn't matter. You can define them in `.m` file. Go to Storyboard/xib and select your view. Go to connection inspector and then check for all connections that are properly connected with all objects of your view. If you found any connection with the sign `!` then remove it and again connect with valid one.

Comment: is there any good clear documentation on understanding xcode debug output?

Comment: Sometimes when you delete an outlet from storyboard and then recreate it in .m file or somewhere else, it does not get deleted from the xml for storyboard. What you can do is open storyboard as source code and then search `PauseButtonTapped` and make sure that it appears as many times as you intended.

Comment: @Simon. - From Apple developer site https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/debugging/

Comment: Also don't forget to follow naming conventions. Here is Apple's guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000146-SW1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: In]

in this window for button, delete all connections, and add them again.